# put all values in for loop to an array

Tags: php

I have the following loop which works and I am receiving the values but I would like to store them to an array - how to go about it?

Existing code:

```
        if(isset($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'])) {
        $extensions = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions']);
            for($j = 0; $j < $extensions; $j++) {
                $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue']);
                for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                    if(isset($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i]) &&
                    is_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i]) &&
                    array_key_exists('dNSName', $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i])) {
                    $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i]['dNSName'];
                    echo $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like the data returned from $value to be stored in an array, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
etc..
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `array_push($arr, $value);`, using the `$arr[] = $value;` has the same effect.

Comment: @user3436467 Also, you should already have the `$arr` variable declared properly, for example declare the variable by using the statement of `$arr=array();` somewhere appropriate before using it :)

Comment: thanks. I put this before the code `$sans = array();` and this in the code `$sans[] = $value;` but i get errors `Notice:  Array to string conversion`

Comment: @user3436467 By the provided code of yours, I believe that's not related to this array assignment, where does the error occur by the way (which line)?!

Comment: ah you made me think a bit more.. issue was because of using echo $sans - instead of print_r($sans)